# substitute substring with a new one calculated from the old one with python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substring, substitution

Is it possible to use Python regular expression to substitute a substring with a new substring "calculated" using the original substring?

Let me give an example:

Suppose I have the substring `userX40`, I want to obtain get the substring `40`, cast to `int`, multiply by 2 and put it back in the original string: so the final result would be `user80`.

I can do this in different passages such as:

```
import re
in_str = "userX40"
original_num = int(re.search("\d+", in_str).group())
out_str = re.search("(.*)[^\d]", lll).group() + str(original_num*2)
```

Is there a way to do it using `re.sub` in one command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with `re.sub`. Provide a callable object that converts the match object into an int, multiplies it, and converts back to string.

```
>>> s = "userX40"
>>> re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: str(2*int(x.group())), s)
'userX80'
```

Comment: `x` in this case represent each matching pattern doesn't it?

Comment: Essentially, yes